# Changing objects' css property with jquery causes insane memory increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resource-leak

I tested for memory leaks with chrome dev tools and garbage collector is doing its job, so there s no circular references. This is such a weird issue, and i don't know what to do anymore. A simple jQuery call `$(e).css("top", 'any value other than current');` will cause the browser to allocate ~5-200mb memory to the tab! Eventually it crashes after maxing out at around 700mb. This happens to all the elements I've tested on different pages. When trying on ie, it would also eventually crash, although memory usage was not reflected in the task manager as it was with chrome. Any ideas what the issue could be? How can I go about analyzing it further.

Comment: Can we see an example showing the issue?

Comment: you want a js fiddle sample? i don t think i could reproduce it there.
here s picture of memory before and after click
http://imgur.com/a/vvPG2

Comment: Its often better to use addClass() and do all css changes in css stylesheet instead of with .css().

Comment: The doc says "Get the value of a computed style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element." How many matched elements do you have ? Complex DOM ?

Comment: im matching a single element